# Keeping transactions in Solidity within gas limit

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm writing a basic fantasy sports smart contract as a way of learning Solidity. The api really only exposes one function to non-admins and it's the "create entry" method. The user submits six teams and the contract validates whether they exist and if they're within cost and then creates an entry. So, there's a decent amount going on.

I'm testing the function and I'm getting an out of gas exception. So, my question is: how do I assess how close I am to getting within gas limit and how do I approach getting it there?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `web3.eth.estimateGas()` function, assuming you're using web3 api.

The question in the link below asks a question relating to the function I mention.

[What are the limitations to estimateGas and when would its estimate be considerably wrong?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/266/what-are-the-limitations-to-estimategas-and-when-would-its-estimate-be-considera)